# Prisma: how to delete a record where it may or may not have children

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

I am trying to figure out how to delete a record created in my graphql, apollo, prisma app, where the record I am deleting may have a has many relationship to another model.

I have a model called IssueGroups. IssueGroups have many issues.

I have a model with:

```
import * as Prisma from "@prisma/client"
import { Field, ObjectType } from "type-graphql"

import { BaseModel } from "../shared/base.model"

@ObjectType()
export class IssueGroup extends BaseModel implements Prisma.IssueGroup {
  @Field()
  title: string

  @Field()
  description: string

  

  @Field(type => String)
  issues: Prisma.Issue[];

  
}
```

A resolver with:

```
import { Arg,  Mutation,  Query, Resolver } from "type-graphql"
import { IssueGroup } from "./issueGroup.model"
import { IssueGroupService } from "./issueGroup.service"
import { IssueGroupInput } from "./inputs/create.input"
import { Inject, Service } from "typedi"

@Service()

@Resolver(() => IssueGroup)
export default class IssueGroupResolver {
    @Inject(() => IssueGroupService)
        issueGroupService: IssueGroupService

    @Query(() => [IssueGroup])
        async allIssueGroups() {
            return await this.issueGroupService.getAllIssueGroups()
        }
    
    @Query(() => IssueGroup)
    async issueGroup(@Arg("id") id: string) {
        return await this.issueGroupService.getIssueGroup(id)
    }

    @Mutation(() => IssueGroup)
    async createIssueGroup(@Arg("data") data: IssueGroupInput) {
        return await this.issueGroupService.createIssueGroup(data)
    }
        // : Promise<IssueGroup[]> {

    
    @Mutation(() => IssueGroup)
    async updateIssueGroup(
        @Arg("id") id: string,
        @Arg("data") data: IssueGroupInput
    ) {
        return await this.issueGroupService.updateIssueGroup(id, data)
    }
    
    @Mutation(() => IssueGroup)
    async deleteIssueGroup(@Arg("id") id: string) {
        return await this.issueGroupService.deleteIssueGroup(id)
    }
}



    // private readonly issueGroupService: IssueGroupService
    
    // @Query(() => [IssueGroup])
    // async issueGroups(): Promise<IssueGroup[]> {
    //     return this.issueGroupService.findAll()
    // }
    
    // @Query(() => IssueGroup)
    // async issueGroup(@Arg("id") id: string): Promise<IssueGroup> {
    //     return this.issueGroupService.findOne(id)
    // }
    
    // @Mutation(() => IssueGroup)
    // async createIssueGroup(
    //     @Arg("data") data: IssueGroupInput
    // ): Promise<IssueGroup> {
    //     return this.issueGroupService.create(data)
    // }
```

A service with:

```
import { prisma } from "../../lib/prisma"
import { Service } from "typedi"
import { IssueGroupInput } from "./inputs/create.input"

import { Resolver } from "type-graphql"
import { IssueGroup } from "./issueGroup.model"

@Service()
@Resolver(() => IssueGroup)
export class IssueGroupService {
  async createIssueGroup(data: IssueGroupInput) {
    return await prisma.issueGroup.create({
      data,
    })
  }

  async deleteIssueGroup(id: string) {
    return await prisma.issueGroup.delete({ where: { id } })
  }

  async updateIssueGroup(id: string, data: IssueGroupInput) {
    const issueGroup = await prisma.issueGroup.findUnique({ where: { id } })
    if (!issueGroup) {
      throw new Error("Issue not found")
    }
    return await prisma.issueGroup.update({ where: { id }, data })
  }

  async getAllIssueGroups() {
    return (await prisma.issueGroup.findMany({orderBy: {title: 'asc'}}))
  }

  async getIssueGroup(id: string) {
    return await prisma.issueGroup.findUnique({
      where: {
        id,
      },
    })
  }
}
```

When I try to delete the issueGroup (which does not currently have any issues, I can see an error that points to issue.delete and says:

> operation failed because it depends on one or more records that were
> required but not found. Record to delete does not exist.

In my form I have:

```
import * as React from "react"
import { gql } from "@apollo/client"

import type { IssueGroupInput } from "lib/graphql"
import { QueryMode, Role, SortOrder, useAllIssueGroupsQuery, useDeleteIssueGroupMutation  } from "lib/graphql"


const __ = gql`
  query AllIssueGroups {
    allIssueGroups {
      id 
      title
      description
    }
  }

  mutation deleteIssueGroup($id: String!) {
    deleteIssueGroup(id: $id) {
      id
      title
      description
      issues  // I have tried both with and without issues in this list
    }
  }
`

export default function IssueGroups() {
  const [deleteIssueGroup] = useDeleteIssueGroupMutation()

  const { data, loading, refetch } = useAllIssueGroupsQuery({
    fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
  
  })
  
  const allIssueGroups = data?.allIssueGroups
  
  const onDeleteIssueGroup = (id: string) => {
    return (
     deleteIssueGroup({ variables: { id } }).then(() => refetch())
    )
      }
  return (
      <List>
          {data?.allIssueGroups.map((issueGroup) => (
          <ListItem key={issueGroup.id}>
            {issueGroup.title}{issueGroup.description}
            <Button onClick={() => onDeleteIssueGroup(issueGroup.id)}>Delete</Button>

          </ListItem>
          ))}
      </List>
  )
}
```

I have seen [this page of the prisma documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/referential-actions) and I think I have followed its advice for how to deal with an issue when the parent issueGroup is deleted.

```
model IssueGroup {
  id              String @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  title           String
  description     String
  issues          Issue[]
  createdAt       DateTime @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updatedAt       DateTime @default(now()) @updatedAt @db.Timestamptz(6)
}

model Issue {
  id              String      @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  title           String
  description     String
  issueGroup      IssueGroup  @relation(fields: [issueGroupId], references: [id], onDelete: SetNull, onUpdate: Cascade)
  issueGroupId    String      @db.Uuid
  subscribers     UserIssue[]
  createdAt       DateTime    @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updatedAt       DateTime    @default(now()) @updatedAt @db.Timestamptz(6)
}
```

However, VS code thinks this is an error. It gives me an error message that says:

> The `onDelete` referential action of a relation should not be set to
> `SetNull` when a referenced field is required. We recommend either to
> choose another referential action, or to make the referenced fields
> optional.

My db is psql, which the prisma docs suggest, should allow SetNull

> PostgreSQL PostgreSQL is the only database supported by Prisma that
> allows you to define a SetNull referential action that refers to a
> non-nullable field. However, this raises a foreign key constraint
> error when the action is triggered at runtime.
>
> For this reason, when you set postgres as the database provider in the
> (default) foreignKeys relation mode, Prisma warns users to mark as
> optional any fields that are included in a @relation attribute with a
> SetNull referential action. For all other database providers, Prisma
> rejects the schema with a validation error.

I can see from [this page](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#remarks-5) of the docs that lists cannot be optional, so I dont think I can follow the advice in the relational page of the docs and make the issueGroup issues[] as optional.

How can i delete the issue (if there were any) at the same time as I delete the issue group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make `issueGroup` optional

```
model IssueGroup {
  ...
  issues          Issue[]
  ...
}

model Issue {
  ...
  issueGroup      IssueGroup?  @relation(fields: [issueGroupId], references: [id], onDelete: SetNull, onUpdate: Cascade)
  issueGroupId    String?      @db.Uuid
  ...
}
```

The actual message from prisma is saying that

> Prisma warns users to mark as optional any fields that are included in
> a @relation attribute with a SetNull referential action

Your relationship has `onDelete: SetNull` - so mark it as optional

Comment: I am able to delete the issueGroup when I do this, but I get an error in the console that says: Cannot return null for non-nullable field IssueGroup.issues.

Comment: rebuild your schema or whichever plugin you using for graphql, this changes schema so needs to be updated

Comment: I did rebuild it. This is the new form of error message that I get when I try this approach.

Comment: your `typedi` model needs to be updated

Comment: i generated new types - but thank you. i get how to find the solution.